# Problem sizing background of img in react app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I'm making a robofriends card app from The Complete Web Developers Course from ZTM (Thanks, Andrei!). The image gets resized, but the background stays all stretched out, my code is identical to the instructors. So I've tried a couple of things like having it in a .css file and changing the background className to have the new dimensions, but the cards stays stretched. The ?size=200x200 snippet is suppose to resize the whole image plus the background. I would appreciate some help with this. Thanks in advance.

```
import React from 'react';

const Card = ({name, email, id}) => {
    return(
    <div className='tc f1 bg-light-green' dib='true' br3='true' 
     pa3='true' ma2='true' grow='true' bw2='true' shadow-5='true'>
       <img alt='robots' src={`https://robohash.org/${id}?size=200x200`}/>
          <div>
                <h2>{name}</h2>
                <p>{email}</p>
          </div>
    </div>
    );
}

export default Card;
```

Comment: Can't really tell what you are trying to achieve without knowing the css related to this component. Or pictures.

Comment: Well, could you clear more, you want to resize the background based on the IMG dimension, but i see you get the same image size every time as you put size 200*200.

Comment: Sorry, I figured out my mistake. Thanks for the feedback.